# Заполнение массива рандомными числами без повтора

Tags: java

Компьютер генерирует пять чисел в диапазоне от 1 до 15 включительно... Код вроде написать удалось с проверкой на одинаковые числа и вроде все генерируется, но иногда при запуске на консоль ничего  не выводится и цикл бесконечный, может кто подскажет что не так?

```
    int random;
    boolean check;

    check = true;

    int[] rand = new int[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < rand.length; i++) {

        while (true) {
            
            random = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 15);
            
            for (int j = 0; j < rand.length; j++) {
                if (rand[j] == random) {
                    check = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (check == true) {
                break;
            }
        }
        rand[i] = random;
    }

    for (int x : rand) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
```

Comment: запускай дебаггер и смотри что не так. Добавь в цикл генерации вывод получаемых чисел в консоль. Есть разные способы выяснить причину самостоятельно.

Comment: проблема у вас нет случая кто сделает check = true

Comment: А пользоваться лучше Set

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант еще так ,  через shuffle. Берете все числа от 1 до 15. Заполняете ими список. Перемешиваете его. Берете 5 элементов списка. :

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int  i = 1; i <16 ; i++ ){
        list.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    int[] rand = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < rand.length; i++){
        rand[i]  = list.get(i);
       
    }
    for (int x : rand) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Так посмотрите.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int random;    
    Set<Integer> unique = new LinkedHashSet<>(); // хранит в порядке добавления, если нужен упорядоченный то используйте TreeSet
    while (unique.size() < 5) {    
      random = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 15);    
      unique.add(random);
    }

    for (int x : unique) {
      System.out.println(x);
    }
  }
```